# Convert R vector to string vector of 1 element

Tags: string, r, vector, arguments, system

Im working with the programming language R now.
I have a vector:

```
a <- c("aa", "bb", "cc")
```

And I want to paste these to a system command, I'm trying it this way now:

```
args <- paste(a, sep=" ")
system(paste("command",args, sep=" "))
```

But now I'm only getting the arguments aa, and I want the arguments aa, bb and cc...

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: for your second paste(), i think instead of sep=" " do you want collapse=" "  ?   `system` is not vectorized but you are giving it three strings.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Use the `collapse` argument to `paste`:

```
paste(a,collapse=" ")
[1] "aa bb cc"
```

Comment: What if it's a named vector and I need the labels as well?